# How to make button width based on text length?

Tags: swift

I want to find a way, how to calculate button width based on text size? As I am using localize for translations, so based on different languages, button text changes, and some of them does not fit into the button size.

Comment: Do you work with autolayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you work with autolayout

it's quite easy. You just need to make sure that the constraints that specify the x coordinate (like `leading space` resp. `trailing space`, also `width`) have a lower priority than the value for the horizontal `content compression resistance priority`.

[image: Width constraint]

[image: Content Compression Resistance Priority]

### If you do manually

You can calculate the size of the text with:

```
guard let buttonFont = button.titleLabel?.font else { return }
let buttonText = "click me"
let size = t.size(withAttributes:[.font: buttonFont])
```

and then set the button's frame size:

```
button.frame.size = size
```

Comment: Actually I don't use autolayout, so this is not helping, but thx anyway :)